# Erase line drawing with UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Did a simple application for line drawing with UIBezierPath, but now need a way to erase the line drawn with UIBezierPath. Is there a way to implement eraser feature for removing the line painting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using an image as background then you can set the same image as brush pattern to draw the bezierpath it will virtually give you the eraser effect. It works for me. :)

```
    brushPattern=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
    // Here image.jpg is you background image
```

Comment: could you please explain. i didnt get you

Comment: @FaheemRahman. Say example: 1. You have a view to draw lines and it has a background image. 2. U are drawing bezier path lines with different color (each path will have color and  a brush pattern) 3. For eraser, use another bezier path and set it's brush pattern to the same image which you are using for your background . It will virtually look like eraser.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(erase)
{
    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeClear alpha:1.0f];
}
else
{
    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An eraser effectively draws a line that's the same color as the background atop every path that's been drawn thus far. You might need to note that it's an eraser line somewhere so that you can update the eraser line's stroke color if the background color changes, otherwise you lose the illusion of erasure.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What if my background is texture image? Is there way to erase the line?

Comment: I am making this up as I go. Someone has likely already solved this, and better. But you can perform path splitting as needed to perform the erasure, instead. The basic idea is that, drawing a single eraser line across a drawn line should split that line into two lines that leave a gap where the eraser was. The two lines should be at the same place in the drawing order as the original single line was.

Comment: @Jeremy, my background has texture, I have no idea how to draw a line that match the texture pattern behind. Any reference for this? Thanks

Comment: @TonyMocha The idea that handles textured backgrounds is to actually perform an erasure by cutting the portion of the path that falls under the erasure out of the path, leaving two paths behind. Diagrammatically, say you have a black line `---`. Now say the user erases the middle pixel. You now have two black lines `- -` with a gap between them. The background will naturally show through that gap.

Comment: @Jeremy, thanks for taking time for reply. I got your idea, but what library or function that I can use to delete the line, quartz2d? I did some searching around, but could not find method to cutting the intersection points (Sorry, I am new to iPhone development. Be patient with me. lol)

Comment: @TonyMocha I don't know of any such library, but I mostly do iPhone dev, not 2-D graphics. You might use `CGPathContainsPoint()`/`-[UIBezierPath containsPoint:]` to see if you have an intersection at a given point. At this point, I would be Googling algorithms; you've run up against basic 2-D graphics, not iPhone-specific stuff. I'd also Google to see if there are better solutions to the erasure problem than the ones I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on Jeremy's answer, it seems like you're trying to do dashed lines. Have you tried using [setLineDash:count:phase:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/setLineDash%3acount%3aphase%3a)

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
CGFloat dashArray[3];
dashArray[0] = 8;
dashArray[1] = 3;
dashArray[2] = 8;
[path setLineDash:dashArray count:dashCount phase: 0.0];
```

Apple has sample code here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BezierPathLab/Introduction/Intro.html