# how to clear the graphics line created with finger touch in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am creating a iphone app that creates signature it works fine but any idea how to clear the drawing from screen which user creates so that it may sign again.here is my code.

here is the link for code

http://pastebin.com/kaaMGNge

Comment: There are many way to draw line. Which way you have used and what u have tried?

Comment: added code please check it

Comment: Check This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177490/erase-line-drawing-with-uibezierpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using core graphics you can use :

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
```

or

```
CGContextFlush(ctx);
```

If you are using UIBezierPath then you can use :

```
[bezierObject removeAllPoints];
```

Comment: added code please check it